# X-Webkit-CSP Security header in the browser

Tags: web-browser, http

What is the X-Webkit-CSP Security header in the browser ? What kind of attacks that we can mitigate from this ?

Comment: It's a legacy header for Content Security Policy from the times when it was still in early adoption phase. This header was used by Chrome for testing CSP. It's now almost completely abandoned - see https://webcookies.org/http-headers/ around 400 sites still use it as compared to over 10k for the standard CSP header.

Answer (score 4):

This is a deprecated HTTP header and it is being replaced by the 
Content Security Policy header.  This will prevent prevent cross-site scripting (XSS), clickjacking and other code injection attacks resulting from execution of malicious content in the trusted web page context.

All the X-* policy headers are non standard headers and following headers are also deprecated and replaced by the CSP.

X-Frame-Options

X-XSS-Protection

X-Content-Security-Policy

Ref : https://content-security-policy.com/

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/csp/